# Extending Alftesco 4

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am interested in extending Alfresco(create our own modules..etc), specially alfresco 4 (including alfresco-share). But I wonder I could not find an official guide for this purpose. Is there any official or unofficial guide for this?

Comment: Tonnes of guides! And Alfresco themselves [offer online and in-person training](http://university.alfresco.com/). One has to wonder if you're really done much research on this...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you yo use maven and start with one of the archetypes provided. See [Managing Alfresco Lifecycle with Maven](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Managing_Alfresco_Lifecyle_with_Maven)